# MySQL - What happens when multiple queries hit the database

Tags: mysql

I am working on a project, which will be used by around 500 employees in my organization. Currently, it's still in development phase, and very few people(around 10) are using it. I'm using MySQL. I just want to know, what happens if many users are doing front end edits and then save, at the same point of time? Some SELECT queries that I've written do take as long as 6 seconds to execute. As only one query can be executed at any point of time, if already a query is in progress, and another hits the database, will it create problem? If this is a common situation in large scale projects, please let me know how can I handle this. I'm not sure, if I've made myself clear :). Any advice or links will be very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From technical aspect, no - nothing bad will happen, the database won't go ballistics and die on you, they're made for purposes like concurrent access.

From logical point of view - something bad will happen. If two people edit the same thing at the same time and then post it at the same time - it gets saved to hard drive one after another. The last one to save is the one whose updates will be on the HDD, effectively causing the first person to lose their changes.

You can approach this problem from several angles. Some projects introduce the concept of locking (not **table** locking but in-app locking). It revolves around marking a record as locked using a boolean column and if anyone tries to access that record for updating, the software says that someone else is editing it. It's something really difficult to implement and for the most time it doesn't work as expected (I think I vaguely remember Joomla! using something like that, it was one of the most annoying features ever).

The other option you have is to save each update as a revision. That way you can keep track on who updated what and when and you never lose any records in case of would-get overwritten. I believe that SO and Wikipedia use that approach and it works really great because you can inspect what two or more people have done and merge their contributions.

Answer (score 3):

Optimistic Concurrency Control
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control

Make sure that each record contains date metadata on last changed/modified time, and load that as part of your data object. Then when attempting to commit the row to database, check the last_modified time in the table to ensure that it is the SAME as the one stored in memory for your object. If it matches, commit it, else throw exception.